# Inserting current date in Microsoft Access database?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When trying to use the DateString to add a date to a microsoft access database, I get the "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.datestring(v=vs.110).aspx) states that "DateString returns the system date in the MM-dd-yyyy format". In the access database, I have set the format to "short date", which has an input mask like so.

[image]

The reason I suspect this problem being related to the date is that inserting the data using this method, but forgoing the date, works fine. Below is my code, if anybody has any ideas for why this might be occurring I would greatly appreciate it.

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    'Change the following to your access database location
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\CampbellBonuses.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "insert into EmployeeBonus ([EID], [IncentiveID], [ProcedureDate], [PatientFirstName], [PatientLastName], [PatientID]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("EID", CType(ComboBox1.ValueMember, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("IncentiveID", CType(ComboBox2.ValueMember, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ProcedureDate", DateString))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("PatientFirstName", CType(txtPFname.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("PatientLastName", CType(txtPLname.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("PatientID", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        'TextBox1.Clear()
        'TextBox2.Clear()
        'TextBox3.Clear()
        'TextBox4.Clear()
        'TextBox5.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format in the table has no importance; it is for default display only.

You could either let Access insert the current date:

```
str = "insert into EmployeeBonus ([EID], [IncentiveID], [ProcedureDate], [PatientFirstName], [PatientLastName], [PatientID]) values (?, Date(), ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

or - in case of concatenating - provide a, for Access, valid *string expression* for the date:

```
DateString = DateTime.Today.ToString("'#'yyyy'/'MM'/'dd'#'");
```

**Edit:**

However, as noted by Eric, specify the parameter as DateTime and pass the true date value:

```
DateTime.Today
```

Comment: While I am still getting this error, I believe your answer is correct. I was mistaken, and I think there are other data type mismatching. I know the nature of the question is different now, but could you possibly given an example of how I might accommodate the different data types of of these parameters?

Comment: Double-check the data types of the fields of the table. IDs are often pure numeric, while you pass everything as text.